# Meteorjs - normal way to iterate user data

Tags: meteor

I’m developing a system by using MeteorJs and I need to fetch all emails and profile of user registered in my MongoDB. This my publish.js

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.publish('Userlist', function() {
       return Meteor.users.find({}, {fields: {emails: 1, profile: 1}});
    });
}
```

and this is where I subscribe my user data in template level res_user.js

```
Template.reg_user.onCreated(function() {
    this.subscribe('Userlist');
});

Template.reg_user.helpers({
    userku: function() {
       let user = Meteor.users.find();
       return user;   
    },   
});
```

this is my html

```
 {{#each userku}}
       <ul>
           <li>{{emails.address}} </li>
           <li>{{profile.name}} </li>
       </li>
 {{/each}}
```

and when I’m trying to iterate it in my html it's not show any emails, just the profile name, after watching this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SByaKi4J0vs)
I find out need some custom helpers to take email, so know I add new helper

```
Template.reg_user.helpers({
   // same code here
   getEmail: function(){
        return this.emails[0].address;
   }
});
```

and call this helpers in my html instead the normal one

```
{{#each userku}}
   <ul>
       <li>{{getEmail}} </li>
       <li>{{profile.name}} </li>
   </li>
{{/each}}
```

Why I can’t use the normal way to take the email.address data? When I see the Mongo structure it's just the same with profile.address. And can someone explain why and when I should use custom helpers like this because its bug me when I try to implement something but don’t know the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Structure of emails in a Meteor user's document**

The structure of the user's emails are an array, mainly because you could [have more than one email address](https://guide.meteor.com/accounts.html#multiple-emails) being associated with your account:

```js
{
  ...
  emails: [
    {
      address: 'someone@provider.com'
      verified: false // or true
    }
  ]
  ...
}
```

**Display emails without helpers**

In order to successfully display the emails without an additional helper, you need therefore to iterate them all:

```html
{{#each userku}}
   <ul>
       {{#each emails}}
       <li>{{this.address {{#if this.verified}}(verified){{/if}}</li>
       {{/each}}
       <li>{{profile.name}} </li>
   </li>
{{/each}}
```

which of course would display all emails, if a user has more than one email associated.

**Display only the first email**

To always display only the first email, you need another helper:

```js
Template.reg_user.helpers({
  firstMail (emails){
    return emails[0];
  }
});
```

and call it like this:

```
{{#each userku}}
   <ul>
       {{#with firstMail emails}}
       <li>{{this.address {{#if this.verified}}(verified){{/if}}</li>
       {{/with}}
       <li>{{profile.name}} </li>
   </li>
{{/each}}
```

**Further readings**

Note, that I also used the `verified` field in my examples, more to read on it here:

https://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-verifyEmail

General reading on that topic here:

https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html